# How can I save data in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I'm making a game that's pretty simple and I really only need to save one `int` for when the game is closed (the scene the payer is at), but all the tutorials and guides I've seen haven't been much help so far.

So basically I want a way to either have the game, resume right where I left off when I quit, have it load a specific scene when you resume playing, or have it save that single `int`. Having it load a specific scene would work best but I can use any of the options stated above.

Comment: _all the tutorials and guides I've seen haven't been much help so far_ What did they taught you that you that you did not like or that was not fitting your needs? In what should the answers given here be different from these tutorials and guides?

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate of our existing general Unity saving Q&A for the time being. If you edit the question to include more details specific to the problem you're having as Alexandre Vaillancourt describes above, then we can re-open the question for new answers.

Comment: Have you tried `PlayerPrefs` (although it's more than a starting point than the definitive answer to your needs)? This is so - basic...