# Is it possible to program a game to resume where it left off when you quit in Unity?

Tags: unity, savegame

I have a game I'm making in Unity and now I'm stuck on saving. Is it possible to program a game to resume where it left off when you quit? Every time I search for this on Google I get nothing. Can anyone tell me if this is possible or not? And if it is how would I do it?

Comment: As written, this is too general; saving & resuming a real time FPS is  going to be different than saving & resuming a turn based card game. What type of game are you making? What have you tried & what specific problems have you encountered?

Comment: I just noticed that it looks like maybe you asked this question instead of editing your [similar, previously closed question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/159349/how-can-i-save-data-in-unity). Please don't repost to get around having a question marked as duplicate - if your question was truly different than the flagged duplicate, edit it accordingly.

Comment: Try searching autosaving in unity

Comment: "Is it possible?" well, do you have any evidence that would suggest that this is *im*possible? If you've seen a feature implemented in dozens to hundreds of games, then there's a very good chance it's not impossible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, write a standard save function for the game.

Second, when you detect a "close" or "quit" event, call that function.

Alternatively, if the data you're saving is fast/small enough, you simply save constantly. See Darkest Dungeon for an example of a game that saves constantly.